# Where is Bluetooth HCI log of Samsung S8 Android 8.0

Tags: android, bluetooth, hci

When Samsung S8 is Android 7.1, bt hci log locates at Android/data. But when update it to Android 8.0, hci log cannot find in any folder.
I also try to generate hci log through commands follow but it does not work neither. These commands works fine with my Pixel 2.

> adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager
>
> adb bugreport > BUG_REPORT.txt

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is tested and verified working for S8, S9, S10+ Android 8.0 through to 9.1:

Input `*#9900#` in the dial pad. An engineer mode menu will pop up.
Click `Run DUMPSTATE/LOGCAT/`. Wait. It may take several minutes for this to generate logs.
Click `Copy To sdcard...` or `Copy to ext sdcard`

`/sdcard/logs` will contain an extensive dump of system logs
`/sdcard/logs/bluetooth/` will contain your timestamped `btsnoop_hci_` log files

Comment: Presumably the Bluetooth snoop log has to be enabled for this to work?